# How to fill the whole background with my image? Android

Tags: android, imageview

I can't seem to fill my background with the image that I have chosen it is in ConstraintLayout how to fix this?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/background" />
```

this is my code of the ImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a scale type in your Image View.

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background" 
        android:scaleType="center"/>
```